# Error when deploying Azure app service on linux : disk quota exceeded

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

I have a .net 6 app deployed on a linux azure app service (P1V2 tier). I deploy the app on a staging slot.
Since yesterday I can't manage to deploy it because on the following error :

**Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: join session keyring: create session key: disk quota exceeded: unknown"}**

In the Quotas menu of the app service, it says 356Mb used on 250Gb so I don't really understand the error message.

In case it helps, I also checked the "Linux - Host Disk Space Usage" but don't really know what to do with it.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: There was an error in menu "Linux - Number of Running Containers per Host"
  : Too many actively running containers (customer) (>=10) detected. I only had 4 apps deployed on the app service plan though. So I moved some apps to another plan and then I managed to deploy my app again. Not very satisfied with the solution as it costs me an extra service plan on apps with very low resources consumption.

Comment: Worked for me as well, moving to different App Service plan. I had to do this even though there is plenty of disk space in my current one so yeah, not to happy with the solution. I'd suggest you to post your answer down below so anyone facing same issue can follow. Thanks olivier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best answer but I managed to resolve my problem by dispatching my apps across more app service plans. When navigating to *Diagnose and solve problems* > *Availability and Performance* > *Linux - Number of Running Containers per Host*, there was an error stating :

> Too many actively running containers (customer) (>=10) detected.

I only had 4 apps with low resources consumption deployed on the plan though.